# Reading and Organizing a CSV without modules?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple different csv files that have a different number of headers. I need to read these csv's without using any modules so I have given it an attempt. How would I print the columns of the different csv's and then be able to get the mean, min, max and standard deviation for each of them, as well as plot them against each other?

Here is what I have so far but in this case the lists have been hard coded in. In this case the file I am reading into it has 2 headers for the date-time and barometer reading but I am also going to be reading other files that have many more headers and more information.

I can use pandas once I have written the csv into a python dataframe so that is why I have imported it. Any recommendations or ideas are much appreciated. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd

def readmyfile(InputFile):
    
    list_date = []
    list_baro = []
    
    with open(InputFile, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            row = line.split(',')
            list_date.append(row[0].strip('"'))
            list_baro.append(row[1].strip('\n'))
    
#     df = pd.DataFrame(list_date[1:])
#     df2 = pd.DataFrame(list_baro[1:])
#     average = np.mean(df2)
    
    print(list_date)
    print(list_baro)
    
readmyfile('barometer-last-year.csv')
```

Some of the data that is in the barometer-last-year.csv:

```
"DateTime","Baro"
"2016-10-09 00:00:00",1021.9
"2016-10-10 00:00:00",1019.9
"2016-10-11 00:00:00",1015.8
"2016-10-12 00:00:00",1013.2
"2016-10-13 00:00:00",1005.9
"2016-10-14 00:00:00",998.6
"2016-10-15 00:00:00",998
"2016-10-16 00:00:00",1002.2
"2016-10-17 00:00:00",1009.8
"2016-10-18 00:00:00",1013.4
"2016-10-19 00:00:00",1015.8
"2016-10-20 00:00:00",1015.7
```

and here is some of the data that I have in the other csv's:

```
"DateTime","Temperature","Temperature_range (low)","Temperature_range (high)"
"2016-10-09 00:00:00",10.66,7.2,13.8
"2016-10-10 00:00:00",8.94,5.6,12.8
"2016-10-11 00:00:00",8.69,5.3,14.3
"2016-10-12 00:00:00",11.55,9,14.9
"2016-10-13 00:00:00",9.4,6,13.3
"2016-10-14 00:00:00",9.85,6.8,13.3
"2016-10-15 00:00:00",10.72,8.2,14.7
"2016-10-16 00:00:00",11.28,7.8,14.5
"2016-10-17 00:00:00",11.84,10,15
"2016-10-18 00:00:00",10.24,8.2,12.7
"2016-10-19 00:00:00",10.2,8,13.4
"2016-10-20 00:00:00",9.76,7.2,12.8
"2016-10-21 00:00:00",7.96,3.7,15.1
"2016-10-22 00:00:00",7.9,5.3,13
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data from the csv files, so the data structure is apparent?

Comment: Sure, let me edit it in.

Comment: What should be the output of function reading this .csv files? What are you planning to do with them? If you read a csv file you already have data in a list, so I want to know if you need to transform the data or simple load would suffice.

Comment: I want to be able to output the max and minimum value of the volumns (apart from the datetime) along with the mean and starndard devidation of each. Then ideally plot them so I can have something visual to compare them against.

Comment: You want to load different .csv files and then plot them on a timeline to show the change of the different parameters in time?

Comment: Yup that's the idea, using matplotlib or something and then also have summary statistics at the bottom which shows min, max, mean and standard deviation of the different columns.

Comment: Okay, please change your question accordingly (it doesn't clearly state what you need), as I provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented `parse_csv()` function inside next code that uses no modules. It supports any separator (e.g. `,`) between cells and any quoting char (e.g. `"`), also it correctly handles separators located inside quoted strings e.g. CSV line `"a,b,c",d` will be handled as two cells `a,b,c` and `d`. Empty lines in CSV are skipped.

First row is handled as columns names. Function returns columns names and rest of rows separately, so that these two can be directly passed to `pd.DataFrame()` constructor.

Function accepts `header` argument (columns names), it should be `True` if header row should be read as first row of CSV file, it should be `False` or contain a list of columns names if CSV file has no header row.

Input CSV file can be passed to function by different ways 1) Through `file` argument which can be either string that contains file path or name, or opened for reading file object. 2) Through `text` argument which can be either string containing CSV text or bytes containing CSV file contents.

In simplest form you just do `columns, table = parse_csv(file = 'test.csv')`.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64403398#main.py)

```
def parse_csv(*, file = None, text = None, sep = ',', quote = '"', header = True, encoding = 'utf-8'):
    assert file is not None or text is not None, f'Either text or file argument should be provided!'
    if text is None:
        if type(file) is str:
            with open(file, 'r', encoding = encoding) as f:
                text = f.read()
        elif type(file) is bytes:
            text = file
        else:
            text = file.read()
    if type(text) is bytes:
        text = text.decode(encoding)
    first, ncols, table = True, None, []
    for line in text.splitlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        parts = line.split(sep)
        i = 0
        entries = []
        while True:
            if i >= len(parts):
                break
            if not parts[i].startswith(quote):
                entries.append(parts[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                entries.append(parts[i][len(quote):])
                while True:
                    if parts[i].endswith(quote):
                        entries[-1] = entries[-1][:-len(quote)]
                        break
                    i += 1
                    entries[-1] += sep + parts[i]
                i += 1
        if first:
            if header is True:
                hrow = True
                header = entries
                ncols = len(entries)
            elif header is False:
                hrow = False
                header = None
                ncols = len(entries)
            else:
                hrow = False
                assert type(header) in [list, tuple], type(header)
                header = list(header)
                ncols = len(header)
            first = False
        else:
            hrow = False
        if not hrow:
            assert len(entries) == ncols, f'Wrong number of columns (expected {ncols}) in row: {line}'
            table.append(entries)
            
    if first and type(header) is bool:
        header = None
    return header, table

    
import pandas as pd



# ----- First example -----

text = """

"DateTime","Temperature","Temperature_range (low)","Temperature_range (high)"

"2016-10-09 00:00:00",10.66,7.2,13.8
"2016-10-10 00:00:00",8.94,5.6,12.8
"2016-10-11 00:00:00",8.69,5.3,14.3
"2016-10-12 00:00:00",11.55,9,14.9
"2016-10-13 00:00:00",9.4,6,13.3
"2016-10-14 00:00:00",9.85,6.8,13.3
"2016-10-15 00:00:00",10.72,8.2,14.7
"2016-10-16 00:00:00",11.28,7.8,14.5
"2016-10-17 00:00:00",11.84,10,15
"2016-10-18 00:00:00",10.24,8.2,12.7
"2016-10-19 00:00:00",10.2,8,13.4
"2016-10-20 00:00:00",9.76,7.2,12.8
"2016-10-21 00:00:00",7.96,3.7,15.1
"2016-10-22 00:00:00",7.9,5.3,13

"""

columns, table = parse_csv(text = text)
df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns = columns)
print('-' * 30)
print(df)



# ----- Second example -----

text = """
    a|b|'c|d'|e
    
    1|2|3|4
"""

ref = None
for header in [
    True, False, ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'],
]:
    columns, table = parse_csv(text = text, sep = '|', quote = "'", header = header)
    df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns = columns)
    print('-' * 30)
    print(df)
    if ref is None:
        ref = (columns, table)
    
    
# ----- Third example -----

import io

with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text)

for file in [
    io.StringIO(text), io.BytesIO(text.encode('utf-8')), text.encode('utf-8'),
    'test.csv', open('test.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8'), open('test.csv', 'rb'),
]:
    columns, table = parse_csv(file = file, sep = '|', quote = "'")
    assert (columns, table) == ref
```

Output:

```
------------------------------
               DateTime Temperature Temperature_range (low) Temperature_range (high)
0   2016-10-09 00:00:00       10.66                     7.2                     13.8
1   2016-10-10 00:00:00        8.94                     5.6                     12.8
2   2016-10-11 00:00:00        8.69                     5.3                     14.3
3   2016-10-12 00:00:00       11.55                       9                     14.9
4   2016-10-13 00:00:00         9.4                       6                     13.3
5   2016-10-14 00:00:00        9.85                     6.8                     13.3
6   2016-10-15 00:00:00       10.72                     8.2                     14.7
7   2016-10-16 00:00:00       11.28                     7.8                     14.5
8   2016-10-17 00:00:00       11.84                      10                       15
9   2016-10-18 00:00:00       10.24                     8.2                     12.7
10  2016-10-19 00:00:00        10.2                       8                     13.4
11  2016-10-20 00:00:00        9.76                     7.2                     12.8
12  2016-10-21 00:00:00        7.96                     3.7                     15.1
13  2016-10-22 00:00:00         7.9                     5.3                       13
------------------------------
   a  b c|d  e
0  1  2   3  4
------------------------------
   0  1    2  3
0  a  b  c|d  e
1  1  2    3  4
------------------------------
  first second third fourth
0     a      b   c|d      e
1     1      2     3      4
```

Comment: Ah this makes a lot more sense. Regarding the text input, is there a way I can input the CSV directly into it without needing to turn it into text? Thanks!

Comment: @Nhyi Currently function deals only with input text string. You just need to read your input file by yourself, just simply do: `with open('file_name.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:  columns, table = parse_csv(f.read())`. Or you can add this file-reading logic into beginning of my function.

Comment: Ah I will give that a try and let you know what happens. I was going to add it to the beginning of the function but wouldn't that cause the splitlines() to be an issue?

Comment: @Nhyi I'll modify now my function so that it can support different types of input (text, file, etc.).

Comment: Ah cheers, much appreciated. I definitely understand how you can put it outside the function, just merging it with the parse_csv function is what I am currently having issues with.

Comment: @Nhyi I've just modified function, now you can provide csv contents in several way one through `parse_csv(text = ...)` then `text` argument should contain text of csv file, or by `parse_csv(file = ...)` then `file` argument should contained either file path or name or file object opened for reading. In simplest form you just do `columns, table = parse_csv(file = 'test.csv')`.

Comment: @Nhyi All variants and examples of usage are included in my script after parsing function definition.